# Is it a challenge to evaluate the indefinite integral $\int \frac{\sin n x}{\sin x} d x$, where $n\in N?$

Tags: integration, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals, telescopic-series

Noting that
\begin{aligned}I_{k}-I_{k-2} &=\int \frac{\sin k x-\sin (k-2) x}{\sin x} d x \\&=2 \int \frac{\cos (k-1) x \sin x}{\sin x} d x \\&=2 \int \cos (k-1) x d x \\&=\frac{2}{k-1} \sin (k-1) x+c_{k}\end{aligned}
A. For even integer $ n=2m,$
\begin{array}{l} \displaystyle  I_{2 k}-I_{2 k-2}=\frac{2}{2 k-1} \sin (2 k-1) x+c_{2 k} \\\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{m}\left(I_{2 k}-I_{2 k-2}\right)=2 \sum_{k=1}^{m} \frac{\sin (2 k-1) x}{2 k-1} \\ \displaystyle  I_{n}=I_{2 m}=2 \sum_{k=1}^m \frac{\sin (2 k-1) x}{2 k-1}+C_1\end{array}
B. For odd integer $ n=2m+1,$
\begin{array}{l}\qquad\qquad \displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{m}\left(I_{2 k+1}-I_{2 k-1}\right)=2 \sum_{k=1}^{m} \frac{\sin (2 k)}{2 k}\\I_{n}=I_{2 m+1}=I_1+\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{m} \frac{\sin (2 k)}{k}+C_{2}=x+\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{m} \frac{\sin (2 k)}{k}+C_{2}\end{array}

***My Question***

How about $$
\int \frac{\sin n x}{\sin m x} d x?
$$

Comment: Here is the answer from [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5BDivide%5Bsin%5C%2840%29m*x%5C%2841%29%2Csin%5C%2840%29n*x%5C%2841%29%5D%2Cx%5D)

Comment: From [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question): "Your question should be clear without the title. After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. **The title is not the first sentence of your question**, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title."

Comment: In the comments of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1432359/695196) 
Andrew D. Hwang mentions that in the special case $n,m \in \mathbb{Z}$, the problem can be reduced to integrating a rational function. I don't think you can do better than that.

Comment: Once again the gausssian hypergeometric function